# Building boost for different versions of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

I have Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 installed.  I want to build boost libraries for 2019 **vc142**. How do I build **vc142** libs instead of **vc143**?

My current method for building is as follows. I'm using `Developer Command Prompt for 2019`, and running the following,

1. `bootstrapper.bat`
2. `b2.exe install --prefix=MY_PATH`

Unfortunately the output lib files are all **vc143**.  I've also tried commenting out `IF "%1"=="vc143" SET TOOLSET=msvc : 14.3` in bootstrap.bat with no success. One of the first outputs when running bootstrap.bat is `Found with vswhere C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community`. I suspect this could be the problem

Comment: Try https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/tools/build/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

adding `toolset=msvc-14.2` to the b2.exe builds the correct version.

`b2.exe install --prefix=MY_PATH toolset=msvc-14.2`

Answer (score 1):

If you run the following command, you will get the answer.

> bootstrap.bat /help

For your requirement, you should run

> booststrap.bat vc142

Other choices are borland, como, gcc, gcc-nocygwin, intel-win32, mingw, vc12, vc14, vc141 & vc143.